# Big Union equivalence class

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, equivalence-relations

Let $R \subset A^2$ be an equivalence class. Prove that $\bigcup_{a\in A}[a]=A$.

I have tried to prove it through double containment:

If $x\in A$, since $x\in [x]$, then $x\in \bigcup_{a\in A}[a]$. So $A\subset \bigcup_{a\in A}[a]$.

Now, if $x\in \bigcup_{a\in A}[a]$, then exists $[m]$, where $m \in A$, such that $x\in [m]$. But $x\in [m]$ is the case (by definition of equivalence class) if and only if $x\in A$ and $xRm$. So, $\bigcup_{a\in A}[a]\subset A$.

Therefore, since  $A\subset \bigcup_{a\in A}[a]$ and $\bigcup_{a\in A}[a]\subset A$ we conclude that is $\bigcup_{a\in A}[a]=A$.

I want to know if my proof is correct, can anyone help me please? Thank you so much gentle people

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: $R$ is then an equivalence relation. For each $a\in A$, we have that $[a]$ is an equivalence class. These are different things. $R\subseteq A^2$ is a binary relation on $A$; $[a]\subset A$...